# Ember + Ember Data, Handling Error Substates at the Application Level, Ember 2.8

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to do something that sounds really simple. I want to render server errors to the outlet of my application.hbs.

Reading this doc, https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/, I am able to detect my errors, but I can't seem to pass the error as a model to my error.hbs by following the given pattern.

If I register the error action handler on my application route as noted, I am able to render my error.hbs template, but I cannot access the context of the error object I'm dealing with. Additionally, my URL route updates, which is not desired.

```
actions: {
    error(err, transition) {
        return this.transitionTo('error');
    }
}
```

Using this handler, I do render error.hbs to my outlet, but I don't get any context from my error object to render to that template. If I try to pass in the error as a model, I get this error:

```
More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: error
```

Right now, whenever an error occurs loading a model, I just get a loading spinner state that hangs forever. I would like, instead, to display the server error(s).

Answer (score 1):

Errors are passed to error substates as the model. The object that was `throw`n or `reject`ed will be your error substate's model and its attributes will be the properties.

For example, if you `throw` or `RSVP.reject` `{ message: 'An Error Occurred' }`, then you can display that in your error.hbs using `{{model.message}}`. I haven't ever seen  `throw`/`reject` primitives work.

[Here is a twiddle that demonstrates working error substates](https://ember-twiddle.com/5b715db233f23107a557a235224871c4) (load the /reject and /undefined routes to see additional examples).

**Code from the twiddle**

templates/application-error.hbs (could also be error.hbs)

```
<p>Application-Error Template</p>
<p>model: {{model}}</p>
<p>model.message: {{model.message}}</p>
<p>model.customMessage: {{model.customMessage}}</p>
```

routes/throw.js

```
model(params) {
  throw { customMessage: 'Reject Error Message' };
},
```

routes/reject.js

```
model(params) {
  return Ember.RSVP.reject({ customMessage: 'Reject Error Message' });
},
```

routes/undefined.js

```
model(params) {
  use.undefined.value;
},
```

Comment: This clears things up a lot. Did you ever find a way that works with throw primitives like throw("foo")?